# Dynamic multiple slide bootstrap carousel using Angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, carousel

I am new to angular 2. I have successfully implemented Bootstrap Carousel in my application. Following is my code :

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="app/images/rsz_clientsearch.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Desert</h3>
                                <p>Desert Image Description</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngFor="let app of apps;let i=index" class="item">
                            <a href="{{app.url}}">
                                <img src="app/images/{{app.imagePath}}" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>{{app.displayText}}</h3>
                                    <p>{{app.description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>
```

Code is working fine, it loads all the slides from  apps object, which is populated from angular component.

I want to make this carousel as multi slide carousel. So that 3 slides will be displayed at a time. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a `Component` for it, and pass the `apps` as an `Input()` to it. Then you can just add multiple selectors with different `apps` passed to each, and the `Component` will handle the rest.

Comment: can you give code sample?

Comment: Make an attempt yourself first, share your attempt here, and I'll try to help you. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. See here for documentation of creating `Components` in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thanks! I will try this approach.